# What files should I include or exclude when uploading a CodeIgniter 4 project to GitHub?

Tags: git, codeigniter, github, codeigniter-4

Codeigniter 4 has made a .gitignore file to my root directory, but I don't know if this file covers everything I shouldn't share on GitHub. Does it automatically exclude all files which store personal information?

For example, I heard there is a file made by CodeIgniter which stores every error log and I don't what to upload that file. My second question is which is that file?

So, I would like to use only `add`, `commit` and `push` commands and `.gitignore` will automatically ignore the files which store personally information, right?

(I have used composer to install Codeigniter 4 and I did not install anything else with it.)

Answer (score 0):

[CodeIgniter 4 `.gitignore` file](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/master/.gitignore).

```sh
#-------------------------
# Operating Specific Junk Files
#-------------------------

# OS X
.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride

# OS X Thumbnails
._*

# Windows image file caches
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db
Desktop.ini

# Recycle Bin used on file shares
$RECYCLE.BIN/

# Windows Installer files
*.cab
*.msi
*.msm
*.msp

# Windows shortcuts
*.lnk

# Linux
*~

# KDE directory preferences
.directory

# Linux trash folder which might appear on any partition or disk
.Trash-*

#-------------------------
# Environment Files
#-------------------------
# These should never be under version control,
# as it poses a security risk.
.env
.vagrant
Vagrantfile

#-------------------------
# Temporary Files
#-------------------------
writable/cache/*
!writable/cache/index.html

writable/logs/*
!writable/logs/index.html

writable/session/*
!writable/session/index.html

writable/uploads/*
!writable/uploads/index.html

writable/debugbar/*
!writable/debugbar/.gitkeep

writable/**/*.db
writable/**/*.sqlite

php_errors.log

#-------------------------
# User Guide Temp Files
#-------------------------
user_guide_src/build/*

#-------------------------
# Test Files
#-------------------------
tests/coverage*

# Don't save phpunit under version control.
phpunit

#-------------------------
# Composer
#-------------------------
vendor/
composer.lock

#-------------------------
# IDE / Development Files
#-------------------------

# Modules Testing
_modules/*

# phpenv local config
.php-version

# Jetbrains editors (PHPStorm, etc)
.idea/
*.iml

# Netbeans
nbproject/
build/
nbbuild/
dist/
nbdist/
nbactions.xml
nb-configuration.xml
.nb-gradle/

# Sublime Text
*.tmlanguage.cache
*.tmPreferences.cache
*.stTheme.cache
*.sublime-workspace
*.sublime-project
.phpintel
/api/

# Visual Studio Code
.vscode/

/results/
/phpunit*.xml
/.phpunit.*.cache

/.php-cs-fixer.php
```

> What files should I include or exclude when uploading a project
> to GitHub?

The above `.gitignore` file should handle the general use case.

> Does it automatically exclude all files which store personal
> information?

If your personal information is stored in the `.env` file at the root of your project, you're safe with the above `.gitignore` file. If in case you defined personal details in a different configuration file, that file should **manually** be added to the `.gitignore` file.

> For example, as I heard there is a file made by CodeIgniter which
> stores every error log and I don't what to upload that file. My second
> question is which is that file?

Error logs are stored under `writable/logs` based on the current date. I.e: `writable/logs/log-2022-04-20.log`.

The declarations *below* that already exist in the above `.gitignore` file are responsible for ignoring **all** log files when committing and pushing your source code.

```sh
# ...

writable/logs/*
!writable/logs/index.html

# ...
```

Resources:

- [`.gitignore` file pattern formats](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format).